# From the viewpoint of us/we, the people?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, pronouns

From the viewpoint of us, the people
/ From the viewpoint of we, the people

Hi guys, I'm not sure which one is correct. I'm trying to say that I am also part of the people, and I'm not sure if I should use 'us' or 'we'?

Comment: "***We the People** of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this [Constitution for the United States of America](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/constitution_transcript.html).*" Use *we*. You'll be in good company.

Comment: Consider: *"From the viewpoint of us, the people who elected you, . . ."*

Comment: Sure, makes sense: We, the people of South Africa,
Recognise the injustices of our past;
Honour those who suffered for justice and freedom in our land;
Respect those who have worked to build and develop our country; and
Believe that South Africa belongs to all who live in it, united in our diversity... http://www.constitutionalcourt.org.za/site/constitution/english-web/preamble.html

Comment: ... We the people of Afghanistan:

1. With firm faith in God Almighty and relying on His lawful mercy, and Believing in the Sacred religion of Islam,

2. Realizing the injustice and shortcoming of the past, and the numerous troubles imposed on our country,

3. While acknowledging the sacrifices and the historic struggles, rightful Jihad and just resistance of all people of Afghanistan, and respecting the high position of the martyrs for the freedom of Afghanistan... http://www.afghan-web.com/politics/current_constitution.html#preamble

Comment: ...But although We the people do acknowledge, ordain and recognize a whole lot of stuff, our viewpoint still belongs to US, not to WE :) The constitutions are all correct, but "From the viewpoint of We" is not

Answer (score 2):

The clause "From the viewpoint of [us/we], the people" is almost certainly constructed as it is in order to invoke and gain resonance from the opening wording in the preamble to the U.S. Constitution, "We the people..." (as quoted in Dan Bron's comment above). That being the case, it seems odd to dump *we* for *us*, just because *us* is the normal pronoun that a person would use in phrases of the form "the viewpoint of us/we." After all, "us the people" has hardly any resonance at all—so why would you go out of your way to use it?

On the other hand, insisting on using *we* in a role normally accorded to *us* makes the resulting phrase sound pretty bad, too—for the same reason that having Claudius say "Render unto me that which belongs to I, Claudius" sounds bad: It tries too hard to retain a word choice that its author hasn't made any structural effort to justify.

If I were in your shoes, I would either set up the sentence so that "we" is the normal, everyday first-person plural pronoun you'd expect someone to use:

> We the people have our own viewpoint: ...

or I would completely abandon the attempt to use "we/us the people" in favor of a less showy, more utilitarian wording:

> From our viewpoint...
>
> From the people's viewpoint...
>
> From the viewpoint of the people...
>
> From the viewpoint of an average citizen...

...secure in the knowledge that, sooner or later, an opportunity will arise to use "We the people" in its appropriate form.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. An equivalent sentence would be "from *our* viewpoint", since the viewpoint is *ours*. This could be expanded to "from the viewpoint of *us*", since the viewpoint belongs to *us* (not to *we*).

So the correct answer is "from the viewpoint of us, the people".

See also (on stack exchage): 
["Us Americans" or "We Americans"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56089/us-americans-or-we-americans) and 
[Difference between "Let us go" and "Let we go"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39573/difference-between-let-us-go-and-let-we-go)

However, the phrase, "we, the people" has a strong connotation of solidarity or unity (if I may call it that), in most of North America, so it may sound better to the ears of your listeners/readers, depending who they are. I guess no one will say "From the viewpoint of we, the people" is wrong.